# How to apply a function to array elements and again organize the same array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having an array named `$question_data` in which a key named ['question_text'] is there and it contains the string in which some HTML tags are also present. Now to clear these questions I'm applying a function called clear_data() on every element of this array. But I want the array back as it is after cleaning up the data. Means other key and values of all elements should be intact only the data of key ['question_text'] should get clear. Can anyone help me in this regard, please? My array is as below:

```
Array
(
    [question_id] => 24803
    [question_parent_id] => 0
    [question_subject_id] => 7
    [question_topic_id] => 272
    [question_directions] => 
    [question_text] => Vitamin <i>B<sub>12</sub></i><sub> </sub>contains metal
    [question_file] => 
    [question_description] => 
    [question_difficulty_type] => 2
    [question_has_sub_ques] => 0
    [question_picked_individually] => no
    [question_appeared_count] => 0
    [question_manual] => 0
    [question_site_id] => 
    [question_created_staff_id] => fbfee12504bf3c4a038d4c9f142f894e
    [question_added_date] => 1326877035
    [question_updated_staff_id] => bf1eda9e6f47ede5fedac85e1016e2d1
    [question_updated_date] => 1338547782
)
```

Comment: `$question_data['question_text'] = '';`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
foreach ($question_data as $k => $v) {
    if ($k === 'question_text') {
        $question_data[$k] = cleardata($v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
function clear_data( &$qd) {
    $qd['question_text']= ''; 
    // or unset($qd['question_text']); to remove it totally
}


clear_data( $question_data);
```